# (Android App) extend webcrawler to execute javascript

Tags: java, android, web-crawler

I was having a look at crawljax, but I can't really understand it.

What I want to do is get html content from a website that is dynamically created, so I would want to execute all JavaScript in order to actually create that content.

I would love it, if somebody could provide me with a real or pseudo example on how to use crawljax or if there's better libs around maybe an introduction to that.

At the end I want a String that I can search for using regex or jsoup.